# GPS location on map in application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, mapkit

I have one application that shows maps. I need to show current position of user and manage to do that with

`[mapView setShowsLocation:YES];`

But when I zoom In or zoom Out map it needs a lot of time to show me that blue pin again.

Is it normal or I need to put something else to keep that blue pin on screen all time???

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[self setCurrentLocation:self._mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate withZoom:1.0];
self._mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;

- (void)setCurrentLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord withZoom:(float)zoomLevel {
    MKCoordinateRegion region = self._mapView.region;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = self.defaultSpanLevel.latitudeDelta*zoomLevel;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = self.defaultSpanLevel.longitudeDelta*zoomLevel;
    region.center = coord;
    [self._mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

You can use this in view will appear Method

> Then You can use mapview delegate methods....
>
> region did change animated:YES {  and set map's region here.... take
>   current user location as region centre.. }
>
> This will solve your problem
>
> }

Comment: yes but every of this solutions works the same as previous. I get blue pin and when I zoom in or out it disappears and then again... horrible...